# How to use javascript to select a selectbox (and engage the UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box that I've put a span near so it looks like:

```
___________________          ___________________
| Sort By: opt1 v |    ->    | Sort By: opt1 v |
|_________________|          |_________________| 
                             :.......opt2......:
                             :.......opt3......:
```

instead of:

```
        ___________                    __________
Sort By:|  opt1 v |    ->      Sort By:| opt1 v |
        |_________|                    |________| 
                                       :..opt2..:
                                       :..opt3..:
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xcHm/4/).  It has all the html, css and jquery I'm attempting to use.

**The Problem:**
The select box only engages when you click on the visible option name.  I need to transfer the click on the spans (one contains "Sort By:" and the other has a custom dropdown arrow img) to a click on the select element.  Here's what I've tried:

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var sb = $('select');
    //none of these work! Please help!
    sb.select();
    sb.click();
    sb.focus();
});
```

Some disclaimers:

- I don't want to select a specific option.  I want to OPEN the selectbox and see all the options, just as if I had clicked on the selectbox.
- I'm not allowed to use the jquery plugin [selectbox](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/).

Comment: Make the span a `label` `for` the select. That's the easiest way.

Comment: Hack: Place the select above the span with a transparent background: http://jsfiddle.net/5xcHm/8/.

Comment: @JanDvorak can you show me on the jsfiddle?  I just tried and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @pimvdb your fiddle breaks in my browser. I could fork it but I can't test it.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: What browser does it break in?

Comment: @pimvdb latest Chrome. The select overlaps its label.

Comment: Update: I tried using the label in an unstyled fiddle. The select is focused, but not expanded (a mobile browser may act otherwise).

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Apparently, it's not a realiable hack :)

Comment: @pimvdb but it's still the best you can get.

Comment: @pimvdb: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/5xcHm/21/) is the best I've been able to do with the hack (must be viewed in firefox, not chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is creating a background image on the select box that contains the text as well as the arrow. Using `appearance: none`, the native arrow is not drawn, and with some left/right padding you can pretty much achieve what you want. Note that this probably is not cross-browser, so make sure to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/5xcHm/16/.

Some canvas code to create background image:

```
var w = $(".sb").outerWidth();
var h = $(".sb").outerHeight();

var canvas = $("<canvas>").attr({
    "width": w,
    "height": h
}).get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

$.extend(ctx, {
    font: "9pt sans-serif",
    textBaseline: "middle"
});

ctx.fillText("Sort By:", 5, h/2+1);

ctx.moveTo(w - 15, 5);
ctx.lineTo(w - 5, 5);
ctx.lineTo(w - 10, 15);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
$(".sb").css("background-image", "url(%)".replace("%", url));
```

And the CSS:

```
.sb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* mind the prefixes */
    padding-left: 55px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
.sortOptionContainer {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I finally convinced my client to use jquery's selectbox plugin, but I like this answer the best of all the ones given.  It's the most consistent between browsers (though not perfect).  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to open a select programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to do this (mimic user interaction with controls) as far as I know. You'll probably have to look into using a select element replacement widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `sort by:` text a label and set its 'for' attribute. No javascript is needed for this:

```
<label for="s_featured">Sort By: </span>
<select id="s_featured" ...>
  ...
</select>
```

While this does not roll down the select in any desktop browser I've tested, it does focus the select, and it is the semantically correct way. It might have the desired effect in mobile browsers.

Rolling the select down is probably impossible, since some user agents may not even have a way to perform that. This is down to the browser what to do when a select is focused through a label.

Note that a multi-select does not even *look* like a normal drop down - and a single-select may not either. W3C only defines the behavior of an element, not how it renders (as an example, note that firefox and chrome render a file input in a very different manner - and both are compliant).